# vi - copy text and pass as argument to escape shell command

Tags: vim, vi

Would like to know if there is a way in `vi` to copy text and paste it as an argument to a shell escape command.

In particular, to read `/var/log/messages`, copy an SELinux alert GUID, switch to `:!`, and run `sealert -l PASTEDGUID`

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5063/9708 may be appropriate? Ctrl-r " to paste the default buffer like in insert mode.

Comment: That does it. Thanks. Your link explained something I haven't seen before, that it's a two step process. Ctrl-r pops up the quotes " on the command line, then you have to press 0 to replace the " with the last yanked value.

Answer (score 0):

In the answer to https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5063, it is described how one may insert the most recently yanked text in insertion mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> followed by <kbd>＂</kbd>.

This also works as you give a command after `:!`.

Instead of a double quote for the most recently yanked text, you may use <kbd>﹡</kbd> to insert the contents of the X11 clipboard, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> to insert the word under the cursor, or <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to insert the current line.

See the documentation for, for example, [`c_CTRL-R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R) and [`c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W), in Vim.

These features are specific to the Vim editor and will not work in Vi or Nvi.  Since you appear to be on a Linux system, you "`vi` editor" is most likely Vim.